# Clean Url without Parameter and ? sign

Tags: php, url

I show in many website that there URLs are clear and perfect, which means in code when I check the href they use are like this:

```
<a href="HTTP://domain.com/123>
```

and when we click on it the accurate go to ABC page that name is taken from database and in my code:

```
<a href="HTTP://domain.com/movie.php?mno=123>
```

How can I do that type of URL for my website?

Comment: You need to look for `url rewriting`.

Answer (score 0):

Using mod_rewrite for Apache. For example, place into a .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)$ movie.php?moo=$1
```

Presuming your valid IDs are made of a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _ and -. Now all queries to `domain.com/ABC09-_` etc. will be redirected to `domain.com/movie.php?moo=ABC09-_`.

Note that you will probably want to actually rewrite the requested entry ID into a proper key-value pair, rather than using it as a query key without a value. In the above, the requested ID would be available under `$_GET['moo']`. In the pattern you posted, `movie.php?ABC`, you would have a different variable for each ID, e.g. 'ABC' would be under `$_GET['ABC']`, etc.

Comment: sorry i made mistake in that now i edited it now CAN I GET THE HELP

Comment: Help is already in the answer I posted. What other help are you in need of sir?

Comment: What did you do, what was the result, and what are the errors?

Comment: i placed that code in .htaccess file and run my page but it shows me domain.com/movie.php?mno=123 in the url no changed

Comment: The way mod_rewrite works here is you put `domain.com/123` in the URL. The URL remains as it is, it'll never show the query string. The query string is only passed to Apache and PHP. Otherwise, if for some reason you want the query string in the URL, you should do redirects instead of rewrites.